# Solr Cloud Document Routing

Tags: solr, sharding, apache-zookeeper

Currently I have a zookeeper multi solr server, single shard setup. Unique ids are generated automatically by solr.

I now have a zookeeper mult solr server, multi shard requirement. I need to be able to route updates to a specific shard.

After reading http://searchhub.org/2013/06/13/solr-cloud-document-routing/ I am concerned that I cannot allow solr to generate random unique ids if I want to route updates to a specific shard.

Cannot anyone confirm this for me and perhaps give an explanation of the best approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can route your documents to a particular shard since it is being managed by the zookeeper.

Solution to your problem is that you should create two collections instead of two shards. Use your 1st collection with two servers and 2nd collection can use the third server and then you can send your updates to particular servers.The design should look like

```
collection1---->shard1---->server1,server2
collection2---->shard1----->server3
```

This way you can separate your indexes as per your requirement.

Comment: The problem with this is that I need a distributed search. I need the results from both shards merged based upon the solr scoring algorithm. What is the information in the link I provided referring to if not a way to update a specific shard?

Comment: You can send updates to a particular collection but retieve from both in one go.

Comment: I have now went round in a circle and think I know what I need - 1 shard, 2 collections! Thankyou. I see people are asking the the question [link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Compatible-collections-SOLR4-SOLRCloud-td4063776.html) and nobody has a formal answer apart from 'the schema should be similar'. Anyway I have posted one last question for my dilemma (I hope!) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148464/solr-cloud-distributed-search-on-collections

Comment: Hi javacreed perhaps you could take a look at my **[new solr question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338324/zookeeper-multiple-collection-different-schema)**. It's connected to the previous 3 questions you answered. Thanks